# How to terminate jupyter cell with python input prompt window?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

First of all, do not laugh at me, <_<.
When using jupyter note book with pycharm, I run a cell like below:

```py
for i in range(10000):
    input()
```

So the window of the `input()` function keeps catching focus(This means I can not click any else of the pycharm window). And I do not know how to terminate this cell. Any suggestions?

Comment: Kernel >> Interupt Kernel or Kernel >> Restart Kernel

Comment: Because of the existance of `input()` function, I can only interact with the prompt window. So I can not click anything provided by pycharm.

Comment: I reproduce your situation and press fn+F2(mac) Ctrl+F2(Win), still can't break/stop, but for expediency, I use auto click app to keep clicking the "cancel" for 10000 times.

Comment: (you might read it as a stupid, obvious question, but let me ask to be sure) crtl+C doesn't work either?

Comment: Ctrl + C didn't work

Answer (score 1):

There should be a stop (■) button on the header bar beside (▶ Run). Select the cell you want to terminate and select stop.